# How to set extra source and drain pins in PMOS power chip

Tags: transistors, pmos

I am using the FDS4685 chip here: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDS4685-D.PDF

It has 4 drain and 3 source pins which I haven't seen before. I only need 1 source and 1 drain, how do I determine whether to connect these pins to ground or high to my 5V supply? Is it wrong to just keep it floating?

Comment: the diagram clearly shows that the pins are all connected together ... there is nothing to determine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tie them together on the board (drains together, sources together.) The multiple pins are provided to reduce the resistance to the FET.

Multiple connections to the same high-current signal are common with high-power / high-current devices. This one supports 8.2A; it needs more than just one SOIC pin to handle that much current.

The other purpose of multiple-lead connections like this is to help with thermal dissipation from the package: the leads conduct heat, too.

Comment: That makes sense given that it has such high current rating. But won't tying the sources and drains cause a short? I see 2 ways to interpret your msg: 
1. Connect my single source connection and single drain connection to the respective PMOS source and drain. The extra source and drain are connected to each other. Won't that cause a short? 
2. Tie all the source/drain lines on the PMOS to my single source/drain connection?

Comment: The FET inside the package has only one source, one drain. The package lead frame makes multiple connections to these signals with individual bond wires. Electrically though they are treated as one signal. The datasheet schematic doesn't show this detail, but it does show all the S and D pins being connected together internally, and they are if you measure them with an ohmmeter. But you still need to connect them together to get the best performance from the FET.

Comment: Connect **all** the source pins to each other, and call that the one source. Connect **all** the drain pins to each other, and call that the one drain. Do not connect the source pins to the drain pins.